# Kohana 3.2 save session in database

Tags: database, session, kohana

Please help me understand, why does the sessions not write in the database?

session config

```
'database'      => array(
    'name'      => 'session_database',
    'encrypted' => TRUE,
    'lifetime'  => 43200,
    'group'     => 'default',
    'table'     => 'sessions',
    'columns'   => array(
        'session_id'    => 'session_id',
        'last_active'   => 'last_active',
        'contents'      => 'contents'
    ),
    'gc' => 500,
),
```

i do that:

```
Session::$default = 'database';    
$this->session = Session::instance();    
$this->session->set('test', 'test');
```

Then I reload the page, and I don't see a new row in table `sessions` in DB

Comment: In case of curiosity: why do you intend to do so?

Comment: i want keep $this->session->set('test', 'test'); in database

Comment: no errors, all right. But session dosen't save in database

Answer (score 2):

If you are using encryption, then you need to make sure you have set an encryption key in the `encrypt.php` config file.

```
'database'      => array(
    'name'      => 'session_database',
    'encrypted' => TRUE,               /* using encryption requires a key */
)
```

/application/config/encrypt.php

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') OR die('No direct script access.');

return array(

   'default' => array(
            /**
             * The following options must be set:
             *
             * string   key     secret passphrase
             * integer  mode    encryption mode, one of MCRYPT_MODE_*
             * integer  cipher  encryption cipher, one of the Mcrpyt cipher constants
             */
            'cipher' => MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,
            'mode'   => MCRYPT_MODE_NOFB,
            'key'    => 'my_encryption_key'
   ),

);
```

Comment: This is exactly right, helped me out a lot.  Thank you.  Kohana's documentation is incorrect- and without checking I blindly named my encryption config file `encryption.php`.  `copy the default config/encryption.php` - http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/security/encryption.  Great framework, horrible documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you did that, but you need to create the table using this exact query:

```
CREATE TABLE  `sessions` (
    `session_id` VARCHAR(24) NOT NULL,
    `last_active` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `contents` TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`session_id`),
    INDEX (`last_active`)
) ENGINE = MYISAM;
```

Comment: exsistCREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sessions` (
  `session_id` varchar(24) NOT NULL,
  `last_active` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `contents` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`session_id`),
  KEY `last_active` (`last_active`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your setting `Session::$default = 'database';` overwrites by  `Session::instance()`.
Try this:

```
$this->session = Session::instance('database');
$this->session->set('test', 'test');
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your logs for errors.

I see that you have set the session data to be encrypted. Make sure that you have defined a 'key' in the encryption config file. You can also try setting the encryption setting for the database session to be false to see if that is causing your error.